# Find the number of sides that intersect between two or more polygons

Tags: python, geopandas

I am currently struggling to find the number of sides that intersect between two or more polygons in a layer, the layer contains around 2700 polygons. All polygons have a rectangular form, as it can be seen it in the following picture. The picture is a small part but everything looks more o less the same
[image]

I have tried using intersection function, but I don’t seem to have proper results, or at least the ones I expected.

In the picture there are numbers on some polygons (I put them there just to explain better), what I want to do is:

- For the polygon 1, I would have just one side that intersect with other polygons
- For the polygon 2, I would have 2 sides that intersects with other polygons
- For the polygon 3, applies the same as polygon 2
- For the polygon 4, I would have just one sides that intersects with other polygon
- For the polygon 5, applies the same as polygon 4

In other words:

```
Polygon Sides
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   1
5   1
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this using GeoPandas or similar moduls?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is similar to:

[Find all neighbors using geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281652/find-all-neighbors-using-geopandas)

but you want count, instead of the neighbour names. Based on the answer to it you can try:

```
import geopandas as gpd

file = r'C:\folder\file.shp'

df = gpd.read_file(file) # open file

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index, "Count"] = df[~df.geometry.disjoint(row.geometry)].shape[0] #Calculate and add number of neighbours
```

You might get a higher count than you want since it will count all neighbours including those sharing "corners", for example polygon 2 and the polygon bottom right of it.

Comment: Thx for the useful link to the other question and the code example. I run some simulations and in the results i got the number 1.0 for those polygons that don´t have any neighbor. So my question would be: is the number 1.0 the polygon itself?

Comment: @Yiyi Yes, it is.